# Acentuação em mysql select exibindo sinal de interrogação "�"

Tags: php, mysql

Hoje migrei meu site para a hostgator e aconteceu esse problema, os acentos estão tudo com uns caracteres �

Os arquivos estão tudo com acento correto no banco de dados

Meu collation no banco de dados esta como: utf8_general_ci

Estou usando a meta: utf-8

Vou colocar meu select para ver se vocês acham algum problema:

```
<?php 
$sql = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM recadao ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3");
while ($exibe = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
?>

<?php echo $exibe['recadao_mensagem']; ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Já fui em mais de 500 lugares e não consegui solucionar o problema.

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema nesse momento!

Comment: Como você fez a migração dos dados?

Comment: Fiz um backup do banco de dados, criei um novo banco de dados e inseri a sql

Comment: @Josimara Tenta `echo utf8_encode($exibe['recadao_mensagem']);`

Comment: Isso resolveu, mas porque sera que aconteceu isto?

Comment: @Josimara Você usa qual IDE? Não deve estar configurado como default UTF-8.

Comment: @Josimara coloquei como resposta à sua pergunta.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Utilize a função PHP [utf8_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-encode.php)

Ficaria assim:

```
echo utf8_encode($exibe['recadao_mensagem']);
```

Obs: Verifique se a IDE que utiliza está configurada como padrão UTF-8.

Answer (score 5):

Tive este mesmo problema e consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

No meu arquivo de conexão com o banco, coloquei o código abaixo:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
```

Funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: Isso resolveu para mim, e você ainda pode fazer em uma execução só: $pdo->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8';
                              SET character_set_connection=utf8;
                              SET character_set_client=utf8;
                              SET character_set_results=utf8;");

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que sua antiga DB também estava configurada com `utf8_general_ci`, então o erro pode estar no backup. Verifique se os arquivos de backup também foram salvos como `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_set_charset( $link, 'utf8');
```

ou

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);
```

Comment: o do Mysqli, comigo funcionou, obrigado você me ajudou.