# Problemas com acentuação em PHP e MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Inseri dados com acento no banco de dados e quando vou listar com php ele me retorna os itens da seguinte maneira
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso resolver isto? Grato :)

Ah, estou usando a colação latin1_swedish_ci na tabela

Comment: Você precisa deixar, base, conexão, arquivos, html no mesmo charset.

Comment: Boa noite, esta pergunta já foi feita várias vezes, recomendo que pesquise, veja uma resposta minha que vai lhe orientar como trabalhar com a utf8 ou is-8859-1: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635 - Segunda dica: Recomento que use textos ao invés de imagens quando se tratar de código. Tenho certeza que vai levar meu comentário como uma critica construtiva. :)

Comment: Qual o encode do seu banco de dados? e qual o encode do seu projeto php?

Comment: Obrigado a todos. Usei o que tem nessa resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14053/25567 e deu certo