# PHP não está retornando os dados da query

Tags: php, sql, json, array

Olá,

estou utilizando o seguinte código para retornar as regiões:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM Regiao';
    $json = array();
    $result = mysqli_query ($conn, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result))
    {
        $regiao = array(
            'id' => $row['Id'],
            'nome' => $row['Nome'],
        );
        array_push($json, $regiao);
    }

    $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
    echo $jsonstring;

    die();
```

O resultado é o seguinte:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "nome": "Norte"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "nome": "Nordeste"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "nome": "Sudeste"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "nome": "Sul"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "nome": "Centro-Oeste"
    }
]
```

estou utilizando o mesmo código porém em outro arquivo com o select diferente:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM Estado';
    $json = array();
    $result = mysqli_query ($conn, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result))
    {
        $regiao = array(
            'id' => $row['Id'],
            'codigouf' => $row['CodigoUf'],
            'nome' => $row['Nome'],
            'uf' => $row['Uf'],
            'regiao' => $row['Regiao'],
        );
        array_push($json, $regiao);
    }

    $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
    echo $jsonstring;

    die();
```

E o resultado no segundo código é em Branco, não me retorna absolutamente nada. Alguém poderia me ajudar por favor?
Obrigado

Comment: Reparei que você está usando letras maiúsculas tanto no nome das tabelas quanto no nome das colunas. Você conferiu se a escrita está correta?

Comment: Oi Phelipe, fui conferir agora a sua pergunta e sim, tanto o nome da tabela quanto os nomes das colunas estão corretos.

Comment: Conferir aqui com cuidado e realmente o código é exatamente o mesmo. A única possibilidade que estou vendo é realmente o nome dos campos da tabela. Vamos ver se outra pessoa consegue encontrar algum outro erro que eu não vi.

Comment: Se executar essa consulta direto no banco, qual é o resultado?

Comment: A única diferença entre as tabelas são a quantidade de colunas, uma tem 2 a outra tem 5, e a quantidade de linhas, uma tem 5 e a outra 27. Mas realmente o nome da tabela e das colunas estão corretas. Muito obrigado, vou aguardar se alguém consegue me ajudar =)

Comment: Executando esse código direto no banco é me retornado os 27 resultados:

Comment: A mostrar registos de 0 - 24 (27 total, A consulta demorou 0.0003 segundos.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provavelmente a coluna nome deve estar preenchida com campos com acentos (Ex. Paraná). Primeiro, tente tirar a coluna nome é veja se ele retorna algum resultado.

Se retornar tente adicionar na sua quero o texto a seguir conforme o link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/74569

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
```

Comment: Funcionou! Apenas alterei o mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); para mysql_query($conn, "SET NAMES 'utf8'"); e funcionou.

Comment: Muito obrigado!